# android admob real advert doesn't load adrequest with code 0 - ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: java, android, admob, banner

About 24h ago I set up a Banner-Ad in my AdMob-console. It is NOT connected to firebase. I do get the test-banners, but no live banners yet.

My activity which requests the banner:

```
private void showStartFragment(){

    //initialize AdMob
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~YYYYYYYYYY");

    //request Banner
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //.addTestDevice("MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID") //my Lenovo K6
    .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    //listener for observing
    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
            Log.i("admob", "onAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
            Log.i("admob", "onAdFailedToLoad");
            Log.i("admob", "error code " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
            Log.i("admob", "onAdOpened");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            Log.i("admob", "onAdLeftApplication");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
            Log.i("admob", "onAdClosed");
        }
    });
```

Excerpt of my layout-file:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYY"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My build.gradle(app):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
          ...
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mysample.app.de.hooorray"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1 Beta"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile project(':vksdk_library')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
}
```

What I tried already:

- Adding test-cases, via test-device-id OR test-banner-id -> **WORKS!**
- compiled different libraries (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0` / `11.4.2` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2`) -> **doesn't work**
- hardcoded triple-checked ADMOB_APP_ID and ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID into the classes / layout-files -> **doesn't work**
- tried on different real devices -> **doesn't work**
- build and installed a release-version of my app -> **doesn't work**

What do I always get in Logat, if I don't use test examples:

```
10-04 20:09:41.228 29844-29935/? W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firbase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
10-04 20:09:42.292 29844-29844/? I/admob: onAdFailedToLoad
10-04 20:09:42.292 29844-29844/? I/admob: error code 0
```

According to [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest) error code "0" stands for **ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.**

I've read a couple of times, that it could take some hours, until a new set up ad will go live, but now 24h hours passed already. I've also read, that in some regions may be no banner advert available, but I can't imagine, that it should be a problem in Germany.

I'm grateful for any hints! Thx in advance!!

Comment: Can you post your app Gradle?

Comment: @Drew, thx 4 quick reply. I updated my build.gradle, how it looks just now.

Comment: What happens when you use the most recent Google ads dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'`?

Comment: The same Logcat-Messages as above: 
"10-04 21:12:42.497 32627-32627/popthebubbleretro.cucoo.de.popthebubbleretro I/admob: onAdFailedToLoad
10-04 21:12:42.497 32627-32627/popthebubbleretro.cucoo.de.popthebubbleretro I/admob: error code 0"

Comment: I dont know if its important: Within my build.grade(BaseGameUtils), which I use for InAppProducts, I use 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.4.0' and 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.0' --> I always have to use the same version as for the  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:XX.X.X/firebase-ads' from my app gradle in order to prevent dex-errors while building the apk.

Comment: One more question: Does my app HAS TO BE published or at least signed in order to show live ads? My app f.e. is now signed but NOT yet published  in Play Store - Although it's now in Play Store as 'unpublished', but connected w AdMob. It doesn't work with this setting now.. I would be grateful for any official sourcesb about this.

Comment: The app does not need to be published or signed in order to show live ads.

Comment: But than I don't know, what could be the reason :\

Answer (score 1):

I found this on [AdMob-Banner-Doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)s:

> Testing with real ads (even if you never tap on them) is against AdMob
>   policy and can cause your account to be suspended. See Test Ads for
>   information on how you can make sure you always get test ads when
>   developing.

So maybe its just blocked somehow or the app needs to be publihed in production? But how can I ensure 100% that banners and interstitials will be shown correctly, wenn the app is finally released?

Answer (score 1):

Day three after setting up my AdMob and I finally got it to work: When I logged into my AdMob-Console they told me smth  in the page header like

> "You add will not be showed, because you did not fill out all account
>   details."

I followed their given link, filled up some additional things and suddenly live ads are showing up.

What I here and now can "officially" confirm for any other searching folks: **You do not need to build a signed apk or publish your app within the Play Store in order to receive life ads!**

**But** actually its not recommended to do so (see above my answer) and at least you shoudld probably not click on your live ads during testing. I enabled my test-device again, now that I can be sure that it will work properly in released production.

Comment: Can you share what are those "things" you  filled up. and also how did you communicate with those guys?